# The role of the first observation in backward algorithm

Tags: algorithm, hidden-markov-models

My question is related to the Backward algorithm. 
The recursive formula for the algorithm is as follows:

sigma j = 1 to N (t+1(j) * a<sub>ij</sub> * b<sub>j</sub>(O<sub>t+1</sub>))
Where t+1(j) is the recursive element, aij is the transition probability from state i to j, and b<sub>j</sub>(O<sub>t+1</sub>) is the omission probability of the observation O at time t+1. 
Given the above, when I start calculating the backward probabilities, it seems that it does not matter what the first observation is, since the observation at time t is not taken into consideration for calculation of the corresponding backward probability. 
For Example, for a sequence of observations A,T,G,A, it does not matter what the first observation , i.e, A in this case, is since its emission probability is not taken into consideration in the backward algorithm. 
I just want to know if my intuition is correct. Otherwise please point me to some reference or explanation which will clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given the above, when I start calculating the backward probabilities,
>   it seems that it does not matter what the first observation is, since
>   the observation at time t is not taken into consideration for
>   calculation of the corresponding backward probability.

That's correct.

`b[t](i)` is the probability of observing the sequence `O[t+1], O[t+2], ..., O[T]` given the hidden state `i` at the time `t`.

One way to think about it is this. The hidden state at the time `t` *independently* affects two things: the observation `O[t]`, and the probability distribution of the subsequent states and observations. So, once the state is fixed, `O[t]` and `O[t+1], O[t+2], ..., O[T]` are conditionally independent (given the value of that state). That's why `O[t]` doesn't appear in the calculation of `b[t](i)`.